# Перенос координат из Openstreetmap в Яндекс.Карты

Tags: openstreetmap

Привет!

При переносе координат полученных в OSM происходит небольшое смещение на Яндекс.Картах. Как избавиться от этого смещения, чтобы метки точно попадали в определенные точки.

Comment: Язык укажите в метке/теге

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, какую технологию используете, что уже реализовали, кукую ошибку получили и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Смещение происходит из-за того, что OSM и Яндекс используют слегка различные географические проекции. Проще говоря, они исходят из несколько различных представлений о том, какие конкретно параметры имеет элипсоид Земли. Соответственно, угловые географические координаты проецируются на виртуальную плоскость их карт слегка по-разному.

Теоретически, существуют формулы перевода координат из одной проекции в другую. Однако на практике это ничем не поможет, поскольку выяснить точные параметры проекции Яндекса скорее всего не удастся. Лично я не пробовал. Но мои коллеги пытались решить эту проблему около двух лет назад и не смогли.

Частично проблему можно решить в локальном масштабе. Например, для отдельного города. Для этого нужно подобрать параметры неизвестной проекции, сопоставив попарно большой набор координат от источников с известной и неизвестной проекциями. Но, во-первых, это достаточно сложно. Придётся писать специальную программу только для этого. А, во-вторых, в результате всё равно получится локальная аппроксимация неизвестной проекции, для которой придётся самостоятельно выводить формулы преобразования. Готовые формулы существуют только для стандартных проекций.

Answer (score 0):

В этом плагине OpenLayers  http://xbb.uz/openlayers/i-Yandex.Maps
, если не ошибаюсь, реализован перевод "яндекс"-проекции в стандартные. Посмотрите.